# Create dynamic function and call them

Tags: javascript

I'm creating javascript function dynamically for each item and i want to call them later, Details in code comment

```
  var i=0;
  $(this).find("Tasks").each(function (i, e) {
    i++;
    function dynamicFunction+ i(){ }
  )};
  // this will result as dynamicFunction1, dynamicFunction2, dynamicFunction3 ... so on
  //now i want to call them under antoher function
  //so my doing this
  for(var k=0;k<=i;k++)
   {
     dynamicFunction + k(); // this is not working
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the same function with different arguments?

Comment: @darkajax same function will not work in my situation,

Comment: Well, this won't work either, so you might as well show the actual situation. I'm pretty sure you can get it working with parameters.

Comment: Try an array of function objects.

Comment: or object of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `function foo() { }` is (roughly) equivalent to `window["foo"] = function() { }`. Therefore to create those dynamically named functions you could do

```
var i = 0;
$(this).find("Tasks").each(function(i2, e) {
    i++;
    window["dynamicFunction" + i] = function() { }
)};

for(var k=0;k<=i;k++) {
    window["dynamicFunction" + k]();
}
```

Though rather than global `window` you should probably use a dedicated variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use individual functions, why not just save them in an array and iterate through that array later:

```
  var funcArr = [];
  $(this).find("Tasks").each(function (i, e) {
      funcArr.push(function(){
          //some code
      });
  )};

  for(var k = 0; k < funcArr.length; k++)
  {
      funcArr[k]();
  }
```